# Can I use getElementById to change it's onclick event value?

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('finalize_btn_top').onclick='bmlAuth();';
        document.getElementById('finalize_btn_bottom').onclick='bmlAuth();';
    }

    function bmlAuth(){
        //
    }
</script>
```

I studied google search results and this should work but it is not working. I put it at the bottom of the page just to be sure the elements have loaded.

```
<input id="finalize_btn_bottom" type="image" name="" value="continue" onmouseover="this.src='<% =strFolder %>/images/b_submitorder_on.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='<% =strFolder %>/images/b_submitorder_off.gif'" src="<% =strFolder %>/images/b_submitorder_off.gif" alt="continue" onclick="bml_submit();">
```

What do I need to do different?

Thanks much!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Turns out I kept looking at the source code for that button with FireBug and it was unchanged. But when I actually started using the button the code I put in bmlAuth started to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in a function reference:

```
var $ = document.getElementById;

$('finalize_btn_top').onclick = bmlAuth;
$('finalize_btn_bottom').onclick = bmlAuth;
```

Comment: OP: In case it isn't clear, your solution will just work by changing `...onclick='bmlAuth()'` to `...onclick=bmlAuth`. @Blender just added some extra sugar for shorthanding.

Comment: `var $ = document.getElementById;` makes the sugar a bit sweeter.